# Opening database in Orientdb in distributed mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, orientdb, pyorient

I am trying to open a database using pyorient in orientdb which was configured and started in distributed mode. But the opening of database is not happening as the process is not completing as well as not throwing any error. I am able to open and access the nodes using the HTTP port - 2480. But when I try to use the binary port - 2424, I am getting this issue.

`import pyorient 
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424)
session_id = client.connect( "xxxx", "xxxxx")
client.db_open( "orient_poc", "xxxx", "xxxx")`

How to resolve this ?

Comment: which version of OrientDB are you using?

Comment: I am using OrientDB version 2.2

Comment: (sorry for delay), ok, only to test, can you try run this code:              import pyorient
 
db_name='python_test'
 
print("connecting...")
client=pyorient.OrientDB("localhost",2424)
session_id=client.connect("root","YOUR_PASSW")
print("OK - sessionID: ",session_id,"\n")
 
client.db_close()

Comment: did this connection test, work?..or you have a problem?

Comment: It worked. But we have not opened any database. I am getting the issue only when I try to open the database.

Comment: so pyorient is ok, could you try to start only one node (for example node1 of you have 2 nodes) and execute the script below?.. After this test,  run all node that you have, and re-execute the script. If you can't run correctly the script, i suggest to you to open an issue on github.

Comment: script:  import pyorient
 
db_name='test'
 
print("connetto al server...")
client=pyorient.OrientDB("10.0.19.37", 2424)
session_id=client.connect("root","root")
print("OK - sessionID: ",session_id,"\n")
client.db_open(db_name, "root","root")
tot=client.db_count_records()
print("Result query ",tot)
client.db_close()

Comment: Yes. I tried but could not connect to the database. Whenever I tried connecting to the database, the server hungs. Speed is also not great. So planning to move to the ETL loader of OrientDB to load data. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a bug in pyorient's CSV serializer. You can't connect to OrientDB in distributed mode.

The OrientSerialization.CSV can't parse the orientDB protocol and goes into an infinite loop.

There is currently a development branch on pyorient that implements the missing binary serialiser (OrientSerialization.Binary).

Install it with:

```
pip install https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/tarball/develop#egg=pyorient
```

Set your serialiser as follows:

```
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424, serialization_type=pyorient.OrientSerialization.Binary)
```

That worked for me.